# I want to split my dataframe based on year

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe containing a column with date values in datetime64 format. I want to split my dataframe in separate dataframes based on year. I wrote the code down below, which works but is super unpractical.

Hope that someone has a better solution!

```
# import libs

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import sample

# Make some random dataframe with two columns

date = np.arange('2005-02', '2008-03', dtype='datetime64[D]')

status = ["X"]*(int(round(0.9*len(date),0))) +['y']*(int(round(0.05*len(date),0)))+['z']*(int(round(0.05*len(date),0)))
newstatus = sample(status, len(status))

data = {'Data': date, 'Status': newstatus}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Extract year from date and make dummies index for splitting

df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Data']).year
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['Year'])

# Split on dummies

df_2007, df_2006, df_2005, df_2008  = df, df, df, df
df_2008= df_2008[df_2008.Year_2008 != 0]
df_2007 = df_2007[df_2007.Year_2007 != 0]
df_2006= df_2006[df_2006.Year_2006 != 0]
df_2005= df_2005[df_2005.Year_2005 != 0]

#Remove Dummies

years = ['Year_2005', 'Year_2006', 'Year_2007', 'Year_2008']
df_2008 = df_2008.drop(years, axis = 1)
df_2007 = df_2007.drop(years, axis = 1)
df_2006 = df_2006.drop(years, axis = 1)
df_2005 = df_2005.drop(years, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
years = df['Data'].dt.year.unique() # I'm guessing Data should be Date really but I'll go along with it.
dfs = {y: df[df['Data'].dt.year == y] for y in years}
```

This creates a dict where the keys are the years and the values are the dataframes corresponding to each year. Which means `dfs[2008]` gives you the dataframe containing the data for the year 2008.